# How to expand div with floated div inside

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="site_content">
    <div id="left_content">
        text
    </div>
    <div id="right_content">
        <%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

My "image.jpg" inside my "right_content" div is larger vertically than my `text` within my "left_content".  "site_content" expands only to the size of the `text` and my "image.jpg" is cut off.  I would like "site_content" to expand to the size of the image.  Here's my CSS:

```
#site_content { 
    width: 950px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 4px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#left_content { 
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 444px;
    padding: 20px 0 5px 25px;
    margin: 0;
}
#right_content {
    float: right;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: With pure CSS you can achieve that with a fake background, but depends a lot on your design.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example of the problem?

Comment: It seems to be expanding automatically in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bMY5X/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the classic [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) problem.

For example, if you added a div after the 2 floated divs and applied `clear: both` attribute you should find the height expands i.e.

```
<div id="site_content">
    <div id="left_content">
        text
    </div>
    <div id="right_content">
        <%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

You could also achieve it in a neater way using CSS e.g.

```
#right_content:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

However, nowadays it's more reliable to make use of the `display` attribute rather than floating divs to achieve a table-like layout e.g.

```
#site_content {
    display: table;
}
#left_content, #right_content {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

would give you the same type of layout i.e.

```
             site_content
_____________________________________
|                 |                 |
|                 |                 |
|  left_content   |  right_content  |
|                 |                 | 
|_________________|_________________|
```